# Is there a way to pass authentication token in Aws Api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

We have an Angular SPA hosted in Aws S3 as frontend and a web service as backend. The backend web service needs to be authenticated to provide a response. But in development environment we hardcoded the backend credentials (authorization token) directly in the javascript. We cannot move it to prod as it has serious risk of being exposed in web browser. So we are asked to create a solution to pass authorization through API gateway with HTTP Proxy Integration. But we found no way to inject the authorization in the Api Gateway through the request to backend web service. Is there a way to pass credentials through Api gateway ??

We have created and tested the Api by passing the query parameters and the authorization as headers before deploying. But after deploying the api we din't find a way to pass the authorization as it states that the query parameters and headers should be mapped from the client request which is our problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called authorizer in api gateway. It acts as a middleware to your backend lambda or whatever you are using. You can make use of it to pass your authorization and validate it. On success it takes you to your backend code and on failure it gives the client unauthorized.

[image]